# Are older cars' cigarette lighters the same as modern

Tags: ford, ranger

Do the Cigarette lighters in the older cars(like my 1986 ford ranger) have the same functionality as modern cars? For example: Should I be able to use a cigarette-lighter adapted phone charger in my car, or is something wrong?

Comment: In fact, some sockets in some modern cars aren't suitable for cigarette lighters despite the dimensions being the same.

Comment: Besides the actual cigarette lighters there are/were also other standard connectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4165 (apparently called "Powerlet")

Comment: Did you have any actual issues with your cigarette lighter outlet?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't check yet I had a weekend away. I will report back when I do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cigarette lighters have been standardized for many years now. Even power outlet plugs are pretty much the same in size and shape, though their power throughput may be lower than an actual cigarette lighter outlet. If you are having issues, first thing to do is try a different adapter. If that still fails, check the fuse. If it's beyond that, you'll need to start tracing wires to see where the power interruption lies.